# Why is dom.innertext was updated and rendered after the while is finished in this example?

Tags: javascript, html

I am pretty new to javascript and am working on an assignment.
The problem I have can be demonstrated via codes below:
For HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>A3Q5</title>
  <script src='xxx.js'> // external js

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <button id="startBtn">Start</button>
    <div id="displayStart">x</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

For the xxx.js code:

```
function setup(){
    document.getElementById("startBtn").addEventListener('click',startRace,false);
}

function startRace(){
    var test =  document.getElementById("displayStart");
    test.textContent = "adsasdasds";
    console.log(test.textContent);
    var c = 5;
    while(c--){
        var counter = 500000000;
        while(counter--){} // try to simulate some delays 

    }
}

window.addEventListener('load',setup,false);
```

so the problem is, when I run the program and click the button, the console prints "adsasdasds" however the div element  is not updated in the browser until the first while loop is done....
Doesn't js run sequentially like java / C++ if no async is specified ?
Hope someone can help me out
The desired result will be : the div is updated before entering the while loop as the sequence of code execution...
Thank you !

Comment: The browser doesn't render anything until the JS returns to the event loop. This allows the script to make multiple changes to the DOM, and the user just sees the final result.

Comment: @Barmar, if that's the case, how would you suggest to fix it ? for some reasons, I need to keep the "delay" thing and I can't use setTimeout..Thank you..

Comment: Why can't you use `setTimeout`? That's the solution anyone will recommend.